# datatable initialization - preventing the need for 2nd post postback

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables.net for creating datatables (jquery)

I'm trying to dinamic create my datatable  (dt) header from server side. what happens is that after the initial post where i get both data and column header info i had a 2nd post to the server (which is irrelevante because i already had my data). So i disable it but then my dt is not properly initialized - i lost "navigation buttons and paging info displays for example 1 of -1 of -1 total records.

is there any way of preventing the 2nd postback but having a "proper" dt initialization? at this point I need to set the  oTable.fnDraw(false) in order to keep a proper initialization

```
this.initialize = function () {

    internalHtmlID = getHtmlIdentifier(id);

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: url
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        internalHtmlID = getHtmlIdentifier(id);
        var oTable = $('' + internalHtmlID + '').dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
            "bServerSide": true,
            "processing" : true,
            "deferLoading": -1,
            "aaData": data.aaData,
            //"aaData": null,
            "aoColumns": data.aoColumns,

            "ajax": {
                "url": url,
                "dataType": "json"
            }

        });
        oTable.fnDraw(false);
    })
    .fail(function (msg) {

    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

You may want to look into using [`deferLoading`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferLoading) to delay the loading of server-side data until second draw.

```
var oTable = $('' + internalHtmlID + '').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
    "bServerSide": true,
    "processing" : true,
    "deferLoading": data.iTotalRecords,
    "aaData": data.aaData,
    "aoColumns": data.aoColumns,
    "ajax": {
        "url": url,
        "dataType": "json"
     }
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asf1aj7L/2/) for demonstration

Comment: damn it.
i had it but setting it to -1 (stupid mistake)